# Entity Framework - Linq NOT IN query

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I've seen several other posts asking similar question but frankly I'm confused. 
I'm trying to do the following sql statement in EntityFarmework and Linq but cant get the 'NOT IN' and 'UNION' working

```
SELECT LmsTeam.* FROM LmsTeam
INNER JOIN Game ON LmsTeam.GameId = Game.ID 
WHERE LmsTeam.Id NOT IN 
(SELECT TeamHomeId as TeamID FROM LmsEventMatch WHERE EventId =1
UNION
SELECT TeamAwayId as TeamID FROM LmsEventMatch WHERE EventId =1)
AND LmsTeam.GameId = 1 AND LmsTeam.Active = 1
```

So I've got the `join` and some of the where clause as below but can't do the `NOT IN` and `UNION` clauses.

```
from t in LmsTeams
join g in Games on t.GameId equals g.Id
  where t.GameId == 1 && t.Active == true
  select t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that:

```
from t in LmsTeams
join g in Games on t.GameId equals g.Id
where t.GameId == 1 && t.Active == true && !(
        (from m in LmsEventMatch where m.EventId == 1 select m.TeamHomeId).Union(
         from m in LmsEventMatch where m.EventId == 1 select m.TeamAwayId)
    ).Contains(t.Id)
select t
```

I haven't tested it because don't have your data context, but think it should be done that way.

**Update**

I think you can avoid `Union` here:

```
from t in LmsTeams
join g in Games on t.GameId equals g.Id
where t.GameId == 1 && t.Active == true && !(
        LmsEventMatch.Where(m => m.EventId == 1).SelectMany(m => new int[] { m.TeamHomeId, TeamAwayId })
    ).Contains(t.Id)
select t
```

Comment: I tried it out in LinqPad and got an error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'LastManStanding.DalEF.Entity.LmsEventMatch'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Oddly the query didnt work in LinqPad but worked perfectley in Code - thanks for youre answer now I just have to start understanding it!

Comment: Maybe something I did, but this would only work if the exclusion set was empty, otherwise I would get the aforementioned "Unable to create constant value of type..." error. N Rocking's outer-join solution below worked for me. (EF 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use Left outer join and keep the records where joined columns are null.

An example is given below:

```
var query = db.Categories    
  .GroupJoin(db.Products,
      Category => Category.CategoryId,
      Product => Product.CategoryId,
      (x, y) => new { Category = x, Products = y })
  .SelectMany(
      xy => xy.Products.DefaultIfEmpty(),
      (x, y) => new { Category = x.Category, Product = y })
  .Where(w => w.Product.CategoryId == null)
  .Select(s => new { Category = s.Category});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write and divide you query as below that will resolve your issue easily.

Also check my post : [SQL to LINQ ( Case 7 - Filter data by using IN and NOT IN clause)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2010/12/sql-to-linq-case-7-filter-data-by-using_15.html)

```
//first do the union of two
var query = ((from d in  LmsEventMatch 
             where d.EventId == 1
              select d.TeamHomeId).
        Union(from e in  LmsEventMatch 
                       where e.EventId == 1
                          select e.TeamAwayId));

//than perform !contains operation for no in
var records =( from t in LmsTeams
join g in Games on t.GameId equals g.Id
  where t.GameId == 1 && t.Active == true && !query.Contains(t.Id)
  select t).ToList();
```

graphical representation of in and not in - linq query

[image]

---

for conversion from sql to linq you can use : [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)
[image]

Comment: `where d.EventId equals 1` - are you sure about that syntax? It's not a `join` condition. `ToList()` in your `list` declaration is another issue - it's gonna cause at least 2 database requests.

Comment: Still incorrect. `from d in  TeamID`. What is `TeamID` here?!?

Comment: I'll give that a go and get back to you - Is it possible in a single query or do i have to use 2?

Comment: @bsheehy01 - you can do it in single query as done in above answer ...but i wrote it like this to make it easy to understand...ultimately this two query get converted one tha you can see in sql profiler...

Comment: I tried out youre code and it worked- thanks for youre input. If I could mark you and MarcinJuraszek as the answers I would but MarcinJuraszek got there first.

Comment: @bsheehy01 - thanks i updated by my answer you can make use of linqer for conversion of sql query to linq

Answer (score 0):

```
var homeIds = LmsEventMatch.Where(em => em.Eventid == 1)
                           .Select(em => em.TeamHomeId);
var awayIds = LmsEventMatch.Where(em => em.Eventid == 1)
                           .Select(em => em.TeamAwayId);
var allIds = homeIds.Union(awayIds);

var query = LmsTeams.Where( 
                t => !allIds.Contains( t.Id ) && t.Active == 1 && t.GameId == 1);
```

Comment: @PranayRana well the OP isn't selecting anything from Game