# Entity framework equivalent for NOT IN

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework-5, subquery

I have a query like this

```
SELECT id 
FROM params 
WHERE valid=1 
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT pid 
                   FROM clientparams 
                   WHERE update = 0 AND client=15) 
LIMIT 25
```

I am trying to convert it to entity framework equivalent:

```
IQueryable<Params> parame = db.Params.Where(p => p.valid.Equals(1)).Except(....);
```

But I am stuck at the point where I need to make an equivalent for the subquery

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Try looking at this question "Entity Framework - Linq NOT IN query" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657086/entity-framework-linq-not-in-query

Comment: Something like `.Where(p=>!clientparams.Select(cp=>cp.pid).Contains(p.Id))` ?

Comment: @Humanier: I tried looking at it, before I posted it, but I am confused because it is using a different way of coding it, and I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: @millimoose thanks, it could also help but i will try the answer below of Esteban because it worked with me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
IQueryable<Params> parame = db.Params.Where(p => p.valid.Equals(1) && 
    !db.clientParams.Any(e => e.pid == p.id && e.update == 0 && e.client  == 15))
                                     .OrderBy(e => e.id) //Order by any field.
                                     .Take(25);
```